# How to store $_POST data to $_COOKIE in moodle php

Tags: php, moodle

I was using the moodle and was not able to get the data of $_POST to $_COOKIE please help me out my code is given below.

```
<?php 
$something = $_POST['UserType'];
$cookie_name = $something;
setcookie(cookie_name, $cookie_name, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>
```

Than on another page I did something like this stated below.

```
<?php
$hello = $_COOKIE['cookie_name'];
echo $hello;
?>
```

But I didn't received any cookie stored in the browser's cookie.

Comment: What is the exact value of `$cookie_name` variable?

Comment: it is the type of user like I have stored "anything" in the userType

Comment: Try setting a cookie first with static data. Like:
`setcookie("static_cookie", "This is my static data", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");` See if that cookie is being set. Then replace the value with `$_POST['UserType']`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$something = $_POST['UserType'];
$cookie_name = $something;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_name, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>
```

I have done this and strangely it worked.. Thank you all..

Comment: Its not strang 
You have the same cookie name and cookie value

Comment: but my cookie name can differ right? If i am wrong pls correct me

Comment: Yes you can
It should be string